# TypeError: Cannot read property "top" of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm not sure what I did wrong. I'm simply just trying to have the console say "Hi" when the top of a div reaches the top of my screen. Here is the html and JavaScript. Right now it says that "top" is undefined.

```
var $window = $(window);

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.logo').css({
    'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+  wScroll /2 +'%)'
  });

  $('.hiker').css({
    'transform' : 'translate(0px, -'+  wScroll /35 +'%)'
  });

   if(wScroll > $('.summer-collection').offset().top) {

    console.log("hi");

  }

});
```

HTML

```
<section class="content"></section>
<article>
  <h1>Summer Collection</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>This is our summer collection, for the real inner survivor in you. This summer collection has a stealth theme for you.
  This is a great series of apparel and accesories to help you travel <strong>INTO THE WILD</strong>. </p>
  <hr>

  <div class=".summer-collection">
    <ul class="product-grid">
      <li><img src="assets/collection/jacket.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Jacket" /></li><!--
      --><li><img src="assets/collection/shorts.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Shorts" /></li><!--
      --><li><img src="assets/collection/hat.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Hat" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/collection/backpack.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Backpack" /></li><!--
      --><li><img src="assets/collection/boot.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Boot" /></li><!--
      --><li><img src="assets/collection/gloves.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Gloves" /></li>
      <li><img src="assets/collection/hammock.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Hammock" /></li><!--
      --><li><img src="assets/collection/tent.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Tent" /></li><!--
      --><li><img src="assets/collection/knife.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Knife" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: `<div class=".summer-collection">` remove the period, it's a class, not a css selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, your div's class should be `summer-collection` (without the dot). Then it should work.

The dot notation is the CSS selector for a class; you aren't supposed to put the dot in your actual HTML.

Comment: oops. I don't know why I even did that haha Just a silly mistake thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the top and left properties are not getting defined, so offset() won't return anything.